# PowerSchool Python Queries

Tags: python, sql, pandas, powerschool

I have successfully set up the plugin I need in PowerSchool to query tables via Python as follows. I looked at the examples in the PowerSchool library [documentation](https://github.com/TEAMSchools/powerschool), but cannot successfully query a specific table (while applying any filters) with the same approaches. I can only get the entire table (when using the SQL query) or "HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: ..." (when using params).

```
import powerschool
import pandas as pd

client_id =  'client id goes here'
client_secret = 'client secret goes here'
my_credentials = (client_id, client_secret)
host_name = 'host name goes here'
ps = powerschool.PowerSchool(host=host_name, auth=my_credentials)
st = ps.get_schema_table('students') 

# I have tried each of these and they all return the entire table
sql = '''SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE last_name IN ('SMITH', 'JOHNSON')'''
params = {'last_name':'SMITH',
          'projection':'last_name'}

stData = st.query(**params)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stData)

stData2 = st.query(body=sql)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stData2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The docs you linked give this example:

```
params = {
    'q': 'id=ge=10000',
    'projection': 'school_number,abbreviation',
}
schools_table.query(**params)
```

Your code does:

```
params = {'last_name':'SMITH',
          'projection':'last_name'}

stData = st.query(**params)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stData)
```

It seems to me that `'last_name':'SMITH'` should be something closer to `'q': 'id=ge=10000'`. I don't know PowerSchool but maybe `'q': 'last_name=SMITH'`?

Comment: `'q': 'last_name=eq=SMITH'`?